# Querying ACL/permissions graph using gremlin?

Tags: graph, permissions, acl, gremlin, gremlin-server

My permissions graph looks like this:

[image: Sample graph image]

In this situation,

1. `user1` has permission on `folder1` through `Group1`.
2. `user2` has direct permissions without any group, though the user is part of `group2` where `group2` doesn't have access over `folder1`.
3. `user3` has permission through group hierarchy, not the direct group to folder access.

I was able to write separate gremlin queries to determine whether a user has permission through one of the groups and user direct permission.

### Checking permission through group

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user1').emit().repeat(out('member_of'))
 .outE('has_permission').has('permission','p1').inV()
 .has('folder','folderId','folder1').hasNext()
```

### User-direct permission

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user2')
  .outE('has_permission').has('permission','p1').inV()
  .has('folder','folderId','folder1').hasNext()
```

But I couldn't figure out the logic in a single query which can check both direct and group to see whether the user has permission or not.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('user').property('userId','user1').as('u1').
  addV('user').property('userId','user2').as('u2').
  addV('user').property('userId','user3').as('u3').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group1').as('g1').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group2').as('g2').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group3').as('g3').
  addV('folder').property('folderId','folder1').as('f1').
  addE('member_of').from('u1').to('g1').
  addE('member_of').from('u2').to('g2').
  addE('member_of').from('u3').to('g3').
  addE('member_of').from('g3').to('g1').
  addE('has_permission').from('g1').to('f1').
  addE('has_permission').from('u2').to('f1').iterate()
```

A general solution to your problem:

```
g.V().has('user','userId',<userId>).
  emit().
    until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
    repeat(out('member_of')).
  filter(out('has_permission').has('folder','folderId',<folderId>)).hasNext()
```

Traversal executed on the sample graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId','user1').
           emit().
             until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
             repeat(out('member_of')).
           filter(out('has_permission').has('folder','folderId','folder1')).hasNext()
==>true
gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId','user2').
           emit().
             until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
             repeat(out('member_of')).
           filter(out('has_permission').has('folder','folderId','folder1')).hasNext()
==>true
gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId','user3').
           emit().
             until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
             repeat(out('member_of')).
           filter(out('has_permission').has('folder','folderId','folder1')).hasNext()
==>true
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. that helped to figure whether user have permission or not.

Comment: followup question on that, now above query helps to figure whether user have permission or not, how can i do extra filtering what exact permission user have. in the graph the has_permission edge label have property 'permission' with some permission lets say 'write'

Comment: gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId',110143).emit().until(__.not(out('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).filter(out('has_permission').has('folder','folderId',191099)).hasNext()
==>true
gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId',110143).emit().until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).filter(out('has_permission').has('permission','V').has('folder','folderId',191099)).hasNext()
==>false
why is the second query returns false though user have that 'V' permission ?

Comment: Got my answer, thanks. im doing like below.gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId',50781).emit().until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).filter(outE('has_permission').has('permission','V').inV().has('folder','folderId',230383)).valueM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel.
just to complicate the above query to check whether user have given permission or not.
below is the answer for any one like me looking for

```
gremlin> g.V().has('user','userId','user3').
           emit().
             until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
             repeat(out('member_of')).
           filter(outE('has_permission').has('permission','V').inV().has('folder','folderId','folder1')).hasNext()
==>true
```